# Scrape prices from Lazada using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the "$94" price from the Lazada marketplace in this URL:

https://www.lazada.sg/products/nike-mens-court-vintage-premium-shoes-white-i1259612749-s5169616981.html?spm=a2o42.searchlist.list.7.43d3747c1CmQse&search=1

Heres my code:

```
import bs4,requests

url = 'https://www.lazada.sg/products/nike-mens-court-vintage-premium-shoes-white-i1259612749-s5169616981.html?spm=a2o42.searchlist.list.7.43d3747c1CmQse&search=1'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,features = "html.parser")
LazPrice = soup.find('div', {'id': 'module_product_price_1'})
print(LazPrice)
```

[image]

Somehow it doesn't seem to be working. Am i using the wrong ID, or soup.find method?

Answer (score 1):

The prices of dynamic listings are contained in a `<script>` tag, under salePrice. The soup actually doesn't contain the `div` tag with id `'module_product_price_1'`.

You need to do some data cleaning to get a clean output of $94.00, something like this:

```
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for i in scripts:
    if "salePrice" in str(i):
        required_script = str(i)
        break
temp = required_script.split('"salePrice":{"text":"')[1]
LazPrice = temp.split('",')[0]
print(LazPrice)
```